# Npm Install Angular 5 compatible version

Tags: angular, npm

Here is my angular version

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.5
Node: 10.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.8.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.8.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.8.4
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.5
@angular/cdk                      7.0.0-rc.0
@angular/cli                      6.2.5
@angular/flex-layout              6.0.0-beta.18
@angular/material                 7.0.0-rc.0
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.4
@schematics/angular               0.8.5
@schematics/update                0.8.5
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.20.2
```

and here is my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.18",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.9",
    "@uimf/uitk": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
```

and i m running the npm install from the same location as the package.json file

```
npm WARN @angular/cdk@7.0.0-rc.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/cdk@7.0.0-rc.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@6.0.0-beta.18 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@7.0.0-rc.0 requires a peer of @angular/animations@>=7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@7.0.0-rc.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@7.0.0-rc.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=7.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-dnd@5.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-dnd@5.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Could someone help me to understand the warning message. From the node modules , i could see angular cdk, flexlayout, material, ng2-dnd(most probably toastr) is not finding the compatible version. Could someone help me how should i ensure the compatabile versions are installed

Comment: Warnings are not errors.

Comment: thanks Brandon. Let me edit my question.. But my intention is, how should i ensure i m installing compatible versions or in otherwords, how can i get rid of these warnings. will it have any effect

Comment: The Angular team tends to update related packages at the same time, so I tend to update every Angular package to it's latest matching version. Occasionally, one will get a minor release ahead, etc, but I don't use differing versions of core modules.